# How do I create a microphone stand?

Tags: audio-hardware, rock-band, guitar-hero

I want to be able to play the guitar and sing at the same times in games like Rock Band and Guitar Hero, so I'm wondering how I can create a microphone stand out of common household objects. The mic stand...

- doesn't have to be rock solid, once the microphone is put in place the mic stand will not be touched.
- should preferably be small enough to easily be put away between gaming sessions.
- should require as little assembly as possible at the start of each session.

Both solutions for playing while standing and sitting are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hit on Google for your question title :)

[Make a mic stand out of a clothing hanger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3aFyH9j4XY#t=2m). (The link skips the two minute long intro.)

Now you just need a high enough support.

Answer (score 2):

My kids use a music stand.

They fold up the bit where the music sits and wrap the wire around the mic to hold it in place.

This works best for the youngest as it's not that high, but the other two put the stand on a box to raise it to their level.

Yes, it does look a bit Heath Robinson but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could always ditch the microphone altogether and just use the XBOX headset for the singing. Here is an article on the topic: [Tech Tip: How To Sing and Play Rock Band Simulatneously.](http://gizmodo.com/335734/giz-tech-tip-how-to-sing-and-play-rock-band-simultaneously)